# Problem with transition: hover on image CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

while trying to build my photography website I ran into an error I can't quite understand. I'm very new to this so it's probably something basic but I don't get it.

I was trying to get the hover effect over an image and after many tries I got it to work. Problem is, every time I load my website the image "jiggles" and there's a super quick hover than disappears.

I'm linking here my HTML and CSS. It looks kind of messy because I've tried to come up with a way to create fixed size boxes where I can insert my pics (and apparently succeeded).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AURORA CATERA -- 2020 ALL RIGHT RESERVED</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel='icon' href='FAVICON.jpg' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
<h1>AURORA CATERA</h1>
    <p>photographer / film maker</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WORKS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/auroracatera"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="img/A236_INSTA_webfit.jpg">
             </div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2>YUMI</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
                </div>
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div>
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div> 
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div>
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div>
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div> 
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div>
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div>
        <div class="box" src="#" alt="ciao"></div> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**here's the CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:300&display=swap');

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
h1{
    color: white;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

p{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    font-family: Cormorant Garmond;

}


.header{
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -105px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;

}
.menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.container{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 70px auto 0;
    display: flex;
    float-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #8D4D4E;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}


.container .box .imgBox{
    position: relative  
}


.container .box .imgBox img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container .box .details{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-size: 30px;
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background: rgba(229,229,229,1.00)
}

.container:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Specify you only want to transition the opacity instead of every property `transition: opacity .5s ease;` also move the transition inside the hover

Comment: Are you editing it locally? Have you ever tried to put it in some live environment like https://codepen.io/pen to test it? If it is what I'm thinking, it probably won't happen when it is online.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I did as you say and now the initial hover has disappeared but the image is still jiggly when I reload the page.

Comment: Yes i thought that might fix it because it's a common issue, now that i have ran your code, i don't see anything jiggles. You mind putting up a code snippet illustrating the issue ?

Comment: @Azametzin I'm using DreamWaever and I'm also loading it online from my hard drive. There's nothing faulty happening in Dreamweaver but then again I'm not loading the page there.

Comment: The issue is happening here? https://jsfiddle.net/rxLupnkm/

Comment: Ohh i see it now, The problem is with the font you're using `Poppins`, which loads way later than the page and begin a big font it cause the h4 element to extend which makes the whole page jiggles, one way i can think of is to have a fixed height on your `h4` equals to `55px` (which is the height of the `h4` after the font is applied) or higher to accommodate for it

Comment: @Azametzin nope, doesn't happen there.

Comment: @ZohirSalak thanks!! That title is going to be replaced by a png with the styled title, so it should go away supposedly?

Comment: an image is worse when it comes to loading resources, because in most cases it will take longer to load, so you'll have to pre define the dimensions which isn't so bad.

Comment: @ZohirSalak so you're suggesting to move my h2 under h4 and to set a height of 55px?

Comment: Oops i meant to say `h1` not `h4` Set a fixed height for the `h1` element as it is the one that changes

Comment: alright, so techinically in css it would go like h1{ height: 55px } ?

Comment: Yes you can add it next to other styles you've already declared on the `h1`

Comment: great, thank you guys!

Comment: Pleasure, Happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you can use a transition property which lets you control whether it is looping or the duration of the animation

the following code below will give you an example of the thing you want but in a more smooth and longer duration result. Hope this solution works :)

```css
.container:hover .overlay{
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```